# Clear timeout not working to end a set timeout?

Tags: javascript, cleartimeout

I am looping over an array of objects, each to display for an amount of time contained in the object. I want to add previous, pause, and next buttons. I declared the timeID variable outside my setTimeout function so that I could call clearTimeout on a click event inside it. the Click event is working as it turns the background color green but the clearTimeout(timeID)isn't...

Here is a screengrab of what it looks like

[image: Here is a screengrab of what it looks like]

```
function generateWorkout() {

  let startButton = document.getElementById("startbutton");

  //click start button to loop through current ecercises
  startButton.onclick = function() {
    var source3 = document.getElementById("runDownHandle").innerHTML;
    var template3 = Handlebars.compile(source3);
    var compiledHTML3;

    //loop through the number of exercises in currentPhaseExercises
    Loop1:
      for (let i = 0; i < currentPhaseExercises.length; i++) {
        let current = currentPhaseExercises[i];
        let duration = current.duration[0];
        let timerType = current.duration[1];
        var timeID;

        //exercise type timed by seconds
        if (timerType === "Seconds") {

          //Start timer based on duration
          timeID = setTimeout(function() {

            //create object based on current exercise to pass into handlebars
            var context3 = {}
            if (!currentPhaseExercises[i + 1]) {
              context3 = {
                runDownTitle: current.exercise.name,
                runDownDuration: current.duration,
                videoSrc: current.exercise.video,
                nextExercise: "Finished!",
              } //context3
            } else {
              context3 = {
                runDownTitle: current.exercise.name,
                runDownDuration: current.duration,
                videoSrc: current.exercise.video,
                nextExercise: currentPhaseExercises[i + 1].exercise.name,
              } //context3
            } // else if

            //Use Handlebars to display exercise
            compiledHTML3 = template3(context3);
            document.body.innerHTML = compiledHTML3;

            //timer for display
            timer(duration);

            //Click for next button
            document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {
              document.getElementById('next').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
              clearTimeout(timeID);
            } // end click

          }, i * duration * 1000) //setTimeout

        } else {

        } // else if

      } //End Loop

  } //End Onlcick

} //generateWorkout
```

Comment: What about changing `var timeID` to `let timeID`?

Comment: That's strange. Though I agree that `let` is the better choice, from what I can tell the way that this is setup it shouldn't matter. Can you place a console log of the timeID in the onclick function and see if it reports, for instance, the same number for all of them or if it correctly outputs differently?

Comment: Before I change the var to let the console.log for timeID in the onClick function reported 7 (the number of objects in the array) every time. After I changed the var to let and when I console.log timeID in the onClick function it reports a number 1-7 incrementally depending on which exercise is displayed.

Comment: Was my answer satisfactory? If so, please mark one with an accepted checkmark and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How long is `currentPhaseExercises.length`? You're creating the timeout in the:

```
for (let i = 0; i < currentPhaseExercises.length; i++) {
```

loop, so you're making a bunch of timeouts, not just one. This simple code exemplifies the problem here:

```js
var timeout;

function go() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Running.");
    }, i * 1000);
  }
}

function stop() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}

go();
stop();
```

This is essentially what you're doing. See how it keeps running after we call stop() to clear it? It's because the for loop made more than one timeout. What you should be doing is something like this:

```js
var interval;

function go() {
  var i = 0;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Running.");

    if (++i >= 5) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

go();
stop();
```

See how it does nothing? That's because we called stop before the interval executed the first time, and it actually stopped it.